# render :json => 'string here' expected result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have done this a thousand times but I'm still not comfortable with how the `render :json` handles strings.

To set a scope let's talk about Rails 3

This is how it behaves right now:

```
...
render :json => 'This is the string'
...
```

Will be returning to the browser:

```
This is the string
```

That's actually not a valid JSON response :S

Ideally it should be rendering something like this:

```
"This is the string"
```

Even the rails guides say:

> You don’t need to call to_json on the object that you want to render.
>   If you use the :json option, render will automatically call to_json
>   for you.

And calling `"This is the string".to_json` is actually returning `"\"This is the string\""` as expected.

```
"This is the string".to_json #=> "\"This is the string\""
```

Am I so wrong ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I agree that this is unexpected behavior at first, but it actually makes some good sense.

Consider, for example, what you would expect this to do:

```
output = {'foo' => 'bar'}.to_json
render :json => output
```

Even though the `to_json` is kinda redundant, you expect the result to be `{foo: "bar"}`. However, note that the result of `{'foo' => 'bar'}.to_json` is actually a string. So, the above code block is equivalent to:

```
render :json => '{foo: "bar"}'
```

If `render` were to JSON-encode strings passed to `:json`, you would get `"{foo: \"bar\"}"`, which is definitely *not* expected behavior.

So here's the deal: `render` checks to see if the `:json` argument is a string. If so, it assumes that it's a JSON string and you already ran `to_json`, and passes the string along. If not, it runs `to_json` on the object.

I think the documentation should probably clarify that, but there you have it. Though it's not exactly intuitive at first glance, I would be surprised if it worked any other way.

Comment: That's not my main concern, my real problem is that the render :json call ends up rendering something that is not JSON at all :S. As I said before, I'm used to this behavior but I think that some validations can be added or at least some sort of default behavior + some param to force another strategy.

Comment: @robertodecurnex: meh. Definitely should not validate the string as JSON, in my opinion. That's waaaay too much of a performance hit to parse a JSON string every time you want to render one. Here's how I think of it: `render`, when passed a string via `:json`, will render that string with the `application/json` content type. If the developer happens to pass another kind of object via `:json`, `render` will be nice and encode it as JSON rather than throw an exception. So, passing a non-string is the edge case, and Rails covers for it.

Comment: How about a Json class ? Is not that hard, it doesn't need to be a heavy implementation. APIs is one of the main topics now a days and JSON the most accepted/used/required format. We don't handle XMLs as strings (usually :P) why are we still handling JSON in that way? RABL is doing a great job but its a templating language, I really think that we need an standard Json class. What do you think?

Comment: @robertodecurnex: umm, isn't JSON a string of data, though? Sure, when we parse XML we might give an XML document a class, but, ultimately, the body of an HTTP request is a string value. Also, note that a parsed XML document needs its own class to handle things like attributes, whereas JSON is exclusively native types, arrays, and key-value pairs. Everything JSON can represent has its own class in Ruby already, so why create another?

Comment: I can see the idea of possibly messing with `String` so that we can tell if a string was the result of a `to_json` call, but what if I want to render a JSON file that I have stored? I shouldn't have to parse the file then pass it to a method that's just going to reencode it. `render :json` should still keep its same behavior regarding strings. By the way, if you're using JSON to just pass strings, consider using plaintext instead.