# Rails "render json: " with string produces output without enclosing braces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am new to Rails and was working on creating an app that calls an existing JSON/Rest based webservice I have.  When I was doing some debugging I just happened to notice that when I call the following where result is an instance of a class I've created:

```
    render json: result

    #output:
    {"storyId":"f4744fd6-d982-4ccc-b176-a22cbb87716b","title":"StoryTitle","mainImageURI":"StoryImageLink","author":"StoryAuthor","description":"StoryDescription"}
```

The output shown in the browser will have enclosing curly braces like I'm used to seeing with json if result is one of my own custom objects, but if the argument is a string then only the string shows up without braces.  For example:

```
    render: json "id: #{result.id}")

    #output
    id: bb9fdc7d-de66-4eca-a37a-287bf0986f6c
```

Would produce the no curly braces output.  It hasn't been a problem, I was just wondering why that is.

Comment: can you share your output?

Comment: render: json "id: #{result.id}")  does not look right, is this just a typo problem/

Comment: yeah, I was just thinking that when I came back to post the output... (the ending parentheses with no starting one I think was just a copy/paste error, but it's still not valid json).  I just tried with the below, though and I still don't see any curly braces added, although it does get rendered as 

`render json: "\"id\": \"#{result.storyId}\""`

`#output 
"id": "202a0097-9d6b-4728-9ef1-9f793542f017"`

Comment: try converting the input to a hash `render: json "{id: #{result.id}}"`

Comment: I could do that, but that gets away from the original question.  My curiosity is around why it automatically adds the parentheses (as I would expect) when converting my custom object to json, but not when converting a string object.  A hash would be something different, right?  I"m very new to Ruby, so maybe  I'm missing something... I will try it out anyway for the sake of experimentation at least :)

Comment: The braces appear if you generate a json object, which you are not. You are turning a string into a .json file which is the same as turning a string into a .text or .html file. if you want your html file to have body tags, you must include them in your string. If you wish that string to represent a json object then you need to add the braces into your string. Google "Rails jsonify" for other ways to create json objects.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `render json: render` renders a .json file. Whereas `render: json "string"`. Renders the evaluation of `json "string"` in Ruby, which is the string itself.

Comment: I see the difference (colon placement?), but I think that might have been a copy/paste error as well.  Unless I"m misunderstanding you, the line I had in the comment in response to formatting callouts
`render json: "\"id\": \"#{result.storyId}\""`  should render a .json file, right?

Comment: And it really is a .json file, but with incorrect syntax. You would have to add the braces yourself, like Mohammad said. The thing is that the evaluation of `result.id` in Ruby is just the `value`, not the `key-value pair` with the braces.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878631/render-json-string-here-expected-result.   

This seems to describe it, which I think is simlar to what you're saying, but the difference in parentheses placement in your two examples (based on my messed up placement) threw me off.

I'll have to experiment with this again, but I think I get what you, and this other answer are saying.  I'll check up on it when I get a chance and respond back.

Comment: nice, can you consider upvoting my answer or marking it as correct, if you think it makes sense?