# Rails: return only integer in get method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request

I am trying to setup Facebook's webhook, and when specifying the callback url, they send a get request to it and expect to receive a code.

I defined an action:

```
def webhook
  render json: { code: '1234567890' }
end
```

So the reponse to the request is `{ code: '1234567890' }` when they are expecting '1234567890'.

I tried to only have:

```
 def webhook
   render json: {'1234567890'}
 end
```

But I get an error.
I also tried to use the head method but nothing is sent back.
How can I only send back an integer ?

Comment: check this. it may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878631/render-json-string-here-expected-result

Comment: I'm not sure if json supports symbols for keys, so you could try 'stringifying your keys - render json: { "code" => "234567890" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nani pointed it out in the comments:

```
def webhook
  render :json => 1826416246
end
```

Works fine !